# Centred resizing with NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a NSWindow which is placed at the position of a NSStatusItem.
The window can change it's size using it's own method `setSize:`, which just get's the right frame for the window like this:

```
- (NSRect)frameForSize:(NSSize)size {
    NSRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x += (newFrame.size.width - size.width) / 2;
    newFrame.origin.y += (newFrame.size.height - size.height);
    newFrame.size = size;

    return newFrame;
}
```

This allows the window to stay centred, if the width is changed.
I can easily call this using code, but when I the user resizes it using the edges of the window, setFrame:display: is called directly. 
There is a delegate method `windowDidResize:notification:`, but if I set the frame there it get's set twice and it lags.

Is there an event that is being called before the window is actually resized?
If not, how should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `NSWindow` and overriding `setFrame:display:` to keep the window centered?

Comment: I have subclassed the window, the problem is that I can't set the origin in this case, ever.

Comment: See my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13054341/1052673).  You are able to set the origin, because you'll call `setFrame:display:` on `super` with the correct (centered) origin for the new size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053227/centred-resizing-with-nswindow#comment17726913_13053227), you've subclassed `NSWindow`.  Assuming that your method `-frameForSize:` is on your `NSWindow` subclass, override `-[NSWindow setFrame:display:]` as follows:

```
- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frameRect display:(BOOL)flag
{
    frameRect = (self.inLiveResize) ? [self frameForSize:frameRect.size] : frameRect;
    [super setFrame:frameRect display:flag];
}
```

I've tested this.  The window will resize smoothly and stay centered the entire time.

Comment: that it does, i know. I've come to this solution before. The problem is that i can never set the default origin. When the panel opens, it's origin is set so it is displayed right underneath of the NSStatusItem. If I override the setFrame:display: method, the window will stay right where it has been initialised, which is in the middle of the screen.

Comment: But I really appreciate your help, therefore a +1 :)

Comment: Could you post screenshots of what happens when you do override `setFrame:display:` as above and when you do not?  I'm not clear on what is undesirable thing is happening when you override the method...

Comment: :) I will.
Basically, i can never set the origin of the window, because it's being overwritten in the setFrame:display: method, so it just stays centered in the middle of the screen when the application launches.

Comment: Great!  I look forward to the screenshots.  Have you tried adding a method with a another name (such as `setSuperFrame:display:`) which just calls through to `setFrame:display:` on super?

Comment: I'm thinking you'd (manually) call this method on the window just before you show it.

Comment: I think setFrame:display: is the only method called if the user resizes the window manually, this is my concern...

Comment: You can [set the origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053227/centred-resizing-with-nswindow/13054341#comment17754437_13054341) using the method I mentioned `setSuperFrame:display:`, and still have the window resize in a centered way by continuing to override `setFrame:display:`.  Does this have the result you're hoping for?  (Calling `setFrame:display:` on `super` will allow you to change the origin--the origin you set won't be overridden by your custom implementation of `setFrame:display:` since you call `super`'s implementation directly.)

Comment: oh, now I see what you're talking about. But I'm not really sure if that's a good solution. Isn't there a method that can be overridden? Which event-method is being called when a NSWindow is being resized manually? I would really only want to do this if the user clicks it.
I don't like making such 'small' exceptions. In a large project, this is very messy and potentially buggy.

Comment: While I don't agree that it's "very messy", I do agree that it introduces is a potential for bugs--or more accurately, unexpected behavior--down the road, long after you've finished writing this window.  Perhaps you would like to only maintain the centeredness while the window is returning `YES` from `-inLiveResize`?  I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I used the panels property self.isAnimating and self.isVisible. It's a pity that I didn't come to this solution myself.