# In a Cocoa macOS application, is it possible to force the resize of a NSWindow to use the different behaviour that is triggered with the option key?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

When you resize a Cocoa macOS window using the ALT (Option) modifier, the window resizes around its center and all corners move, while the normal behaviour is that the window's top left corner keeps its position. Is it possible maybe subclassing NSWindow to obtain the same result by default, not pressing the option key while resizing a window ? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Have you tried any `NSWindowDelegate` methods?

Comment: Specifically, you should be looking at `windowWillResize:toSize:`. From the documentation: "While the user is resizing a window, the delegate is sent a series of `windowWillResize:toSize:` messages as the window’s outline is dragged. The window’s outline is displayed at the constrained size as set by this method."

Comment: I have explored this possible solution but the delegate method returns a NSSize struct, I would need a method that returns a NSRect in order to obtain that effect, because I would need to change the origin of the frame too... What do you think ?

Comment: A returned `NSSize` won't do. I'll have a look.

Comment: [Centred resizing with NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053227/centred-resizing-with-nswindow/13054341#comment17754437_13054341) looks promising but it doesn't quite work.